# Identify entries in a global offset table

Tags: elf, got

I'm attempting to write some ELF parsing logic (in C).  Specifically, I'm trying to identify which entries in the GOT correspond to which functions.

I've crafted a simple program which contains references to `malloc` and `free`.  Some relevant excerpts from `readelf -a a.out`:

```
Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x630 contains 2 entries:
    Offset             Info             Type               Symbol's Value  Symbol's Name + Addend
0000000000003fc8  0000000100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT     0000000000000000 free@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
0000000000003fd0  0000000500000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT     0000000000000000 malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
No processor specific unwind information to decode

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND free@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.34 (3)
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
     4: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
     5: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     6: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
     7: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
```

I know how to use `.dynstr` to get the names of the symbols in `.dynsym`.  However, how is readelf populating the symbol names in `.rela.plt`?  I'm not seeing anything in the definitions of either `Elf64_Sym` or `Elf64_Rel` which would help.  At first, I thought the `st_shndx` field in `Elf64_Sym` would be relevant but readelf is showing that value as `SHN_UNDEF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information **is** contained in the `Elf64_Rel` structure.  Specifically, the `r_info` field:

> This member gives both the symbol table index with respect to which the relocation must be made and the type of relocation to apply.

The `ELF64_R_SYM` macro can be used to extract the offset from this field.  As seen in the `.rela.plt` description in the OP, `free`, for example, has an index of 1 which corresponds to entry 1 in `.dynsym`.